# Author-date referencing overridden

Tags: natbib

I'm using the `natbib` package and would like author-date referencing format. I have the following setup in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{harvard} %(also tried apalike)
\bibliography{mylibrary}
```

Compiling leads to number format in the pdf with an error 'Bibliography not compatible with author year citations' and the commands:

```
\providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers
```

in the `.aux` file. 
I had previously used the author-date format with no trouble so I'm not sure why this error has suddenly occurred.
I'm using TeXnicCenter with MiKTeX on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you checked the formatting of the bibliography items. If there is a mistake there, the bibliography can revert to number format. Common mistakes involve mixing up "[" and "{"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean in the bibtex file itself or within the latex document e.g. the \citep commands?

Comment: My comment actually came from using \bibitem[]{} in the document file and I am therefore now uncertain how these errors translate into a bib-file. Would it be possible to post a [mnimum working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/19384) of your document and bib-file that reproduces the error?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems that the issue related to an entry in the .bib file which didn't have a date, hence natbib overrode the author-date format. Fixing the problem required repairing the databse but also deleting the .aux and .bbl files otherwise the error persisted even with a corrected database.